# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…". in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to center my map in d3.js. I have found this code and changed a little bit .I could'nt manage to do it. I'm getting this error. How can I fix it. I'm new to javascript.

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Set a style for our worldshape-data -->
<style>
  path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    fill: steelblue;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- implementation of the hosted D3- and TopoJson js-libraries -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

  <!-- map creation -->
  <script>
    // canvas resolution
    var width = 1000,
      height = 600;

    // defines "svg" as data type and "make canvas" command
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);


    // shorten the svg.append command
    var g = svg.append("g");

    // load data and display the map on the canvas with country geometries
    d3.json("turkey.json", function(error, topology) {

      var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0]).precision(0);
      var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
      var bounds = path.bounds(topology);


      var scale = .95 / Math.max((bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]) / width,
        (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]) / height);
      var transl = [(width - scale * (bounds[1][0] + bounds[0][0])) / 2,
        (height - scale * (bounds[1][1] + bounds[0][1])) / 2
      ];
      projection.scale(scale).translate(transl);

      g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.turkeytopo)
          .geometries)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
    });



    // zoom and pan functionality
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .on("zoom", function() {
        g.attr("transform", "translate(" +
          d3.event.translate.join(",") + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        g.selectAll("path")
          .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
      });

    svg.call(zoom)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is part of my json country data.

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
    "turkeytopo": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "bbox": [25.66652800000014,
        35.820178,
        44.83384,
        42.106301
      ],
      "geometries": [{
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "arcs": [
          [
            [0]
          ],
          [
            [1]
          ],
          [
            [2]
          ],
          [
            [3]
          ],
          [
            [4]
          ],
          [
            [5]
          ],
          [
            [6]
          ],
          [
            [7]
          ],
          [
            [8]
          ],
          [
            [9]
          ],
          [
            [10]
          ],
          [
            [11]
          ]
        ]
      }]
    }
  },
  "arcs": [
    [
      [1726,
        8274
      ],
      [2, -33],
      [-22,
        0
      ],
      [-7, -21],
      [-43, -47],
      [-16, -4],
      [-12,
        25
      ],
      [-17,
        13
      ],
      [-36, -25],
      [-33, -6],
      [-11,
        13
      ],
      [-1,
        66
      ],
      [-17,
        14
      ],
      [-12, -52],
      [-58,
        81
      ],
      [-28,
        24
      ],
      [-62,
        16
      ],
      [-14,
        19
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "transform": {
    "scale": [0.001916922892289215,
      0.000628675167516752
    ],
    "translate": [25.66652800000014,
      35.820178
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `path.bounds` correctly. From the API documentation `path.bounds`

> Returns the projected planar bounding box (typically in pixels) for
>   the specified GeoJSON object. ([v4](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#path_bounds))
>
> These components use the GeoJSON format—a standard way of representing
>   geographic features in JavaScript. ([v3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md))

You are passing path.bounds a topojson object, instead, try:

```
var bounds = path.bounds(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.turkeytopo));
```

You can always use the centering coordinate as well, as indicated by the bbox property in your topology. The projection would look something like:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(2000)
  .center([34.5,38.5])
  .translate([width/2,height/2]);
```

*Scale is dependent on svg size.*